# Как скрыть Float Action Button при скролле ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Пробовал с CoordinatorLayout как в [этом туториале](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons#converting-from-listview-to-recyclerview) но не сработало. Мне кажется это из за того что у меня `ListView` находится внутри `SwipyRefreshLayout`

Погуглил, но везде говорится только о RecyclerView либо ListView без обертки.

Вопрос: Как все таки скрыть/показать FAB если ListView в обертке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я добился этого добавлением листенера к лв. Вот пример:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {    

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                fab.animate().scaleX(1f).scalY(1f).start();
                flag = true;
            }           
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (flag){
                fab.animate().scaleX(0f).scalY(0f).start();
                flag = false;
            }

        }
    });
```

Вот кстати отличная [библиотека](https://github.com/nisrulz/sensey) облегчающая работу с тачивентами.

Comment: Мне выдало ошибку `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.animate()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Значит пытаетесь анимировать кнопку которой еще нет. Советую сделать дебаггинг.

Comment: Добавил изменения чтобы анимация работала правильно.

Comment: К сожалению, Исчезает,  обратно не появляется

Comment: Добавил анимацию появления.

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ. Подскажите пожалуйста, а как сделать так чтобы fab показывался только при скролле вверх, а исчезал при скролле вниз?

Comment: Так как в лв нет возможности посмотреть куда скролиться контент нужно использовать либо `RecyclerView` либо воспользоваться той библиотекой о которй я написал в ответе.

Comment: Ааа, спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

Для ListView, видимо, нет значений проскроленных пикселей. Засим приведённое ниже решение подойдёт только для RecyclerView.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if (dy > 0 || dy < 0 && mSearchFAB.isShown()) {
            mSearchFAB.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mSearchFAB.show();
        }
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }
});
```

Comment: C `ListView` тоже возможно. Посмотрите мой ответ.

Comment: @ArnisShaykh, я знаю что возможно) Просто там нельзя это сделать отталкиваясь от изменений по осям. Только от стейта. И не очень понятно почему вы в ответе анимируете FAB не стандартным её способом

Comment: Потому что не пользуюсь гугловской фаб а делаю свои кастомные. По привычке написал) к тому же более универсально)

Answer (score 0):

Изменил метод @arnis-shaykh. Я сделал вот так. Дошел до конца - скрыл, наверх - показал. Если элементов мало, вообще не скрываем

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (visibleItemCount < totalItemCount)
            {
                if (totalItemCount - firstVisibleItem == visibleItemCount)
                    fab.animate().scaleX(0f).scaleY(0f).start();
                else fab.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).start();
            }
        }
    });
```